# InfoPath 2010 Form Load for SharePoint 2010 Lists

Tags: list, infopath, list-view

I'm using InfoPath 2010 to customize the View and Edit options of a SharePoint 2010 list.  The view and edit pages, therefore, are displayifs.aspx and editifs.aspx.

I have a Form Load operation in InfoPath 2010 that I only want to run when the Edit option (from the SharePoint List) is used, however, it currently runs when either both the View or Edit options are selected.  Is there a way to force the InfoPath Form Load to only function when the user Edit's the list item?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get what I needed. If anyone is interested, here is what I did. 

1. Added a boolean list item
2. Selected "(Item) Display Form" from List Tools > List> Customize > Modify Form Web Parts > Content Type Forms
3. Added a Query String (URL) Filter Web Part
4. Created a paramenter name and a default value (can be either "true" or "false")
5. Sent the value from the Query String (URL) Filter Web Part to the InfoPath Form Web Part using the list item I created in step 1
6. Repeated steps 2-5 for the "(Item) Edit Form", but use the opposite default value
7. Customized form with InfoPath (List Tools > List> Customize > Customize Form)
8. Used the values on the "Form Load" functionality to control variables using the value sent from the Query String (URL) Filter Web Part

Comment: Thank you very much for that post and answer.
It helped me and saved a lot of research. One small correction: In step 1, you add a new column to the list, right? Regards, Matthias

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you are correct.  Step 1, the addition of the boolean field, is in the same list.  You can pretty much use any type of field since you're passing a value to the InfoPath form.  You'll just need to build business rules in the form for the value you pass into the form.